# ACSM extension missing on Firefox

Tags: mac, firefox

I use a Mac (12.4) with FF (102.0.1) and am having problems with acsm files. They do not download with th eext ension and Adobe Digitl reader will not open them. The problem does not occur when I use Safari so it must be a FF issue.
I can , of course, use Safari to download these files but I would rather use FF which is my default browser.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am having problems downloading acsm files. I file downloads but it has no extension. Adobe DIgital Editions will not open it. If I use Safari, the file downloads with the acsm extension and opens correctly. I tried adding the acsm extension to the file downloaded by FF but ADE still will not open it.